# What's the value of the area of the triangle with sides $3\sqrt2$, $\sqrt{26}$, and $\sqrt{20}$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> The sides of an acute-angled triangle measure
> $3\sqrt2$, $\sqrt{26}$ and $\sqrt{20}$.
> Calculate the area of ​​the triangle (Answer:$9$)

My progress...

Is there any way other than Heron's formula since the accounts would be laborious or algebraic manipulation for the resolution?

$p=\frac{\sqrt{18}+\sqrt{20}+\sqrt{26}}{2}\implies S_{ABC} =\sqrt{p(p-\sqrt{20})(p-\sqrt{26})(p-\sqrt{18})}$

Comment: What is wrong with using the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heron's formula, with sides $a,\,b,\,c$ equal to square roots of rational numbers, is easier to use if you rewrite it as$$\tfrac14\sqrt{4b^2c^2-(b^2+c^2-a^2)^2},$$which is the form in which it's first obtained in a proof of Heron's formula from the cosine rule. In the case $a^2=18,\,b^2=26,\,c^2=20$, we get $\tfrac14\sqrt{2080-28^2}=\sqrt{130-49}=9$.

Comment: thanks for help..with this formula it is much simpler

Comment: +1. I generally find it easier to remember the symmetric, multiplied-out form of Heron's radicand $$-a^4-b^4-c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2$$ It's like the expansion of $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2$, but with sign changes on fourth-powers ... which may scare you into thinking that the value leans negative, but happily it doesn't for a triangle. (The factored form $(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)$ lets you *see* that each of the factors has, say, an $a$, but only one of them is negative, re-confirming the $-a^4$ in the expanded form.) There's a tad more arithmetic with this form, but everything's a trade-off.

Comment: @Blue Thanks for your comment. Analogous pros & cons for [Bretschneider's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretschneider%27s_formula) are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @J.G.: I ran out of characters. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a method (generating two different proofs in fact) that does not use Heron's formula.

Having observed the following relationships:

$$20=4^2+2^2, \ \ \ \ 26=5^2+1^2,$$

we can "embed" the triangle into a coordinate grid in this way:

[image]

where we have, in the different right triangles, Pythagoras theorem giving:

$$AB=\sqrt{20}=\sqrt{5^2+1^2}, \ \ AC=3 \sqrt{2}=\sqrt{3^2+3^2}, \ \ BC=\sqrt{4^2+2^2}$$

It remains to subtract to the area of rectangle $DEBF$ the areas of the right triangles:

$$4 \times 5 - (5 \times 1/2 + 4 \times 2/2+3\times 3/2)=20-11=9.$$

In fact, with this figure, we do not need to do all these calculations. It is simpler to use [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem), saying that the area of a polygon whose vertices are on a square grid is given by:

$$A=\color{red}{i}+\frac{b}{2}-1$$

where $i$ is the number of interior points and $b$ the number of boundary points, giving in our case:

$$A=7+\frac{6}{2}-1=9$$

[image]

(Many thanks to A-B-C who has recalled me this method I had forgotten).

Comment: This is very refreshing!

Comment: @Math Lover Yes, the triangles look to be drawn in a swimming pool...

Comment: great alternative gratitude

Comment: There is also another nice method following this one. See for more info: http://www.se16.info/hgb/triangle.htm

Comment: A-B-C Thank you! I knew method number 7 (with the so-called ["Pick's formula"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick's_theorem) ) but had completely forgotten it ! It is funny that the example they take is with the very same triangle.

Comment: In fact, I have included this solution into my answer because it can be of interest to others. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

If $a = \sqrt{18}, b = \sqrt{20}, c = \sqrt{26}$, first note that $a^2 + b^2 \gt c^2$ where $c$ is the longest side. That means it is an acute-angled triangle and the orthocenter is inside the triangle. So if we drop a perp from vertex $A$, then using Pythagoras,

$AD^2 = 20 - x^2 = 26 - (\sqrt{18} - x)^2$

$ \implies x = \sqrt 2$ and we get $AD = \sqrt{18}$

So, $A = \frac 12 a \cdot AD = 9$

By the way, if you notice that $26 - 8 = 20 - 2$ and $\sqrt{8} + \sqrt{2} = a$, you can get to altitude $AD = \sqrt{18} ~$ a bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

Use cosine law,

$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos{\gamma}$

$(\sqrt{26})^2=(3\sqrt2)^2+(\sqrt{20})^2-2\cdot3\sqrt2\sqrt{20}cos\gamma$

$\implies cos(\gamma) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\Rightarrow sin(\gamma)=\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$

$A=\frac12\cdot 3\sqrt2\cdot \sqrt{20}\cdot sin(\gamma)$

$\implies...A=9$

Answer (score 1):

Given a triangle ABC with side lengths $a=3\sqrt{2}$, $b=\sqrt{26}$ and $c=\sqrt{20}$...

Heron's formula: $S_{ABC}=\sqrt{s\left(s-a\right)\left(s-b\right)\left(s-c\right)}$, for $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$

---

Before substituting in the values for $a$, $b$ and $c$, let's substitute the formula $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ into $S_{ABC}=\sqrt{s\left(s-a\right)\left(s-b\right)\left(s-c\right)}$, so that Heron's formula only contains the variables $a$, $b$ and $c$.

$S_{ABC}=\sqrt{s\left(s-a\right)\left(s-b\right)\left(s-c\right)}\to S_{ABC}=\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{2}\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-a\right)\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-b\right)\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-c\right)}$

$\to S_{ABC}=\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{2}\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-\frac{2a}{2}\right)\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-\frac{2b}{2}\right)\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-\frac{2c}{2}\right)}$

$\to S_{ABC}=\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{2}\left(\frac{-a+b+c}{2}\right)\left(\frac{a-b+c}{2}\right)\left(\frac{a+b-c}{2}\right)}$

$\to S_{ABC}=\sqrt{\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)\left(-a+b+c\right)\left(a-b+c\right)\left(a+b-c\right)}{16}}$

$\to S_{ABC}=\frac{\sqrt{\left(a+b+c\right)\left(-a+b+c\right)\left(a-b+c\right)\left(a+b-c\right)}}{4}$

$\to S_{ABC}=\frac{\sqrt{2a^2b^2+2a^2c^2+2b^2c^2-a^4-b^4-c^4}}{4}$

---

Now that we have Heron's formula in terms of only $a$, $b$ and $c$, let's substitute in their respective values.

$S_{ABC}=\frac{\sqrt{2a^2b^2+2a^2c^2+2b^2c^2-a^4-b^4-c^4}}{4}$

$S_{ABC}=\frac{\sqrt{2\left(3\sqrt{2}\right)^2\left(\sqrt{26}\right)^2+2\left(3\sqrt{2}\right)^2\left(\sqrt{20}\right)^2+2\left(\sqrt{26}\right)^2\left(\sqrt{20}\right)^2-\left(3\sqrt{2}\right)^4-\left(\sqrt{26}\right)^4-\left(\sqrt{20}\right)^4}}{4}$

$S_{ABC}=\frac{\sqrt{2\left(18\right)\left(26\right)+2\left(18\right)\left(20\right)+2\left(26\right)\left(20\right)-324-676-400}}{4}$

$S_{ABC}=\frac{\sqrt{936+720+1040-324-676-400}}{4}$

$S_{ABC}=\frac{\sqrt{1296}}{4}$

$S_{ABC}=\frac{36}{4}$

$S_{ABC}=9$